# Ubuntu 17.10 can not run netease-cloud-music

Tags: ubuntu, audio-player

```
~$ netease-cloud-music
```

I got this:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall 0281
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000008003119
#0 0x7f774c3dcaeb <unknown>
#1 0x7f7747b27150 <unknown>
#2 0x7f774ed37b73 <unknown>
#3 0x7f774ed36b0b <unknown>
#4 0x7f7747b27150 <unknown>
#5 0x7f7747848c87 epoll_pwait
#6 0x7f774c452728 <unknown>
#7 0x7f774c45032e <unknown>
#8 0x7f774c3d4f9e <unknown>
#9 0x7f774c408ee0 <unknown>
#10 0x7f774c3f736a <unknown>
#11 0x7f774c427de8 <unknown>
#12 0x7f774c42479d <unknown>
#13 0x7f7747b1b7fc start_thread
#14 0x7f7747848b0f clone
  r8: 0000000000000002  r9: 0000000000000008 r10: 0000000000000000 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 0000000000000000 r13: 00007f774f60c2e9 r14: 0000000000003119 r15: 00007f7736982228
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007f774f60c2e8  bp: 0000000000000119  bx: 0000000000000000
  dx: 0000000000000001  ax: 0000000000003000  cx: 0000000008003119  sp: 00007f7736982210
  ip: 00007f774ed37b73 efl: 0000000000010202 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000006
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000008003119
[end of stack trace]
```

It seems like there is a problem about the theme.
This problem happened after I received the latest system upgrate.
I used also Ubuntu 17.10 before,but everything is OK,netease-cloud-music runs well.

Comment: also run into the same problem LOL..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem. I fixed it by closing sandbox environment.

You can just execute `netease-cloud-music --no-sandbox %U` and it would work fine.(may needs `sudo`)

Further, you can modify the `desktop` configuration file so you can open it via desktop icon.

- edit the desktop file `netease-cloud-music.desktop`. Maybe in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`.
- Change the `Exec = /the/path/to/netease-cloud-music` to `Exec=/the/path/to/netease-cloud-music --no-sandbox %U`

Now, reboot your computer and enjoy the music.